# Proving $d_E$ is a Metric on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification, alternative-proof

This question rather then wanting help w.r.t (M3) (The Triangle Inequality ) with can be done by using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. I would like advice regarding (M1):

$d_E(\mathbf {q,p}) = 0 \iff \mathbf {p =q }\text{ } \forall \mathbf{p,q} \in \Bbb R^n $.

An immediate proof that jump to mind is as follows:

$$d_E = 0 \iff \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n (q_i-p_1)^2 } =0 $$

$$\iff \sum_{i=1}^n (q_i-p_1)^2 =0 $$
and  since  $q_i, p_i \in \Bbb R  \text{ } \forall i \in \{1,...,n\}$

then $(q_i-p_i)^2 =0 $  $\forall q_i \in \mathbf q \land \forall p_i \in \mathbf p$

$\Rightarrow (q_i-p_i) =0 \Rightarrow q_i = p_i  \forall i \in \{1,..,n\}$

hence  $\mathbf q = \mathbf p$

However I find this  proof rather cumbersome. Am I being pandantic? or Is there a more elegant and/or concise way to represent this?

Comment: This is a good proof, provided to change $p_1$ to $p_i$ everywhere ;-)

Comment: @Siminore Thank you for pointing that out.